# AWS architecture - traffic mirroring

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, api, migration, amazon-cloudfront

We are going to migrate our database from Aurora Serverless to Aurora Cluster. Before that, we'd like to test the performance of the new database in a real-time traffic scenario. We have thought about cloning the current API Gateway, targeting the new database and mirroring traffic from the production API to the test API.

Is this crazy? Is there any way to to achieve this without affecting the performance of the production API Gateway? (there is a CloudFront in front of our API Gateway)
Maybe listen for API Gateway events in Cloudwatch and trigger a lambda to run the query against the test API gateway?

Comment: Rather than risk destabilizing your production system, you should do this in a test environment. Actually, two test environments, identical except for the backend database. Then run the same test workloads against each.

Comment: Hi @jarmod This is an imposed requirement. We need to measure the performance of the test environment in a real-time traffic scenario. We already have the two environments ready, we just need to clone the traffic from the production system and forward it to the test environment. If this where not possible, we would do the typical load tests with tools like JMeter, HammerDB or similar

Comment: Is Lambda Edge is your friend here?. You can add one origin request, redirect to different API gateways. Another thing I see is if you can check the pattern and then redirect to the API gateways.

Comment: Hi @NgenCMS it's an option, but I'm afraid it may affect production performance. I think we are going to abandon this idea and make load testing with HammerDB. Thank you.

Comment: @Juanlu - how did you proceed? I'm thinking of the same use case.

Comment: Finally, we forgot about the traffic mirroring approach and ran some load tests on the new database. Idk if something has changed in the last months